# Automatic coercion of numeric types

Tags: haskell

I have a type

```
data Value = Int Integer
           | Float Double
           | Complex (Complex Double)
           | ... (other, non-numeric types)
```

with an associate error type

```
data ValueError = TypeMismatch Value | ... (other constructors)

type ThrowsError = Either ValueError
```

and I want to implement generic binary operations over the type, with automatic coercion to the highest type in the heirarchy, and error signalling in case one of the operands isn't a numeric type, i.e. a function

```
binaryOp :: Num a => (a -> a -> a) -> Value -> Value -> ThrowsError Value
```

so that I could write, for example,

```
(binaryOp (+)) (Int 1) (Int 1)      ==> Right (Int 2)
(binaryOp (+)) (Int 1) (Float 1.0)  ==> Right (Float 2.0)
(binaryOp (+)) (Int 1) (String "1") ==> Left (TypeMismatch (String "1"))
```

Is there a simple way to do this? My first thought was to define something like

```
data NumType = IntType | FloatType | ComplexType
```

along with functions

```
typeOf :: Value -> NumType
typeOf (Int _) = IntType
...

promote :: Value -> Value
promote (Int n)   = Float (fromInteger n)
promote (Float n) = Complex (n :+ 0)
```

but I'm having difficulty making it work. Any advice?

---

A bit more context. I'm writing a Scheme interpreter, and I want to implement the Scheme [numeric tower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_tower).

In fact I want to achieve something slightly more complicated than what I explained, because I want something applicable to an arbitrary number of arguments, along the lines of

```
binaryOp :: Num a => (a -> a -> a) -> [Value] -> ThrowsError Value
```

which would be implemented with `foldl1`, but I feel that if I can solve the simpler problem then I will be able to solve this more complicated one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
data NumType = IntType | FloatType | ComplexType | NotANumType
  deriving (Eq, Ord)

binaryOp :: (forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a) -> Number -> Number -> ThrowsError Number
binaryOp op x y
   = case typeOf x `max` typeOf y of
          ComplexType -> Complex (asComplex x `op` asComplex y)
          ...
```

I think you will need to enable the Rank2Types extension (insert `{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}` at the top of your source file) to properly state the type of `binaryOp`, and I'm not sure I've got the syntax right...

The type of `binaryOp` is more complex than you thought because `binaryOp` chooses what `a` is when it calls `op`. What you wrote would have `binaryOp`'s caller choosing what `a` is, which is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I have a basic version working now! This is an example of what's so great about StackOverflow. I didn't even know that you could existentially quantify over the domain of a function (although it seems kind of obvious now I've seen it...) so I may never have found this on my own.